# How do you name the phenomenon of being single at a late age?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation

Specifically, a woman who is single at a late age.
"Late bachelorette", "late singleness"... It doesn't sound right.

Is there a way to describe it as an adjective and also as a noun?

I am asking because I am trying to translate an article from another language.

**Edit:** After reading the commenmts, I understand that some further clarification is needed. I was trying to find a term for someone who has never been married and has already passed the "culturally accepted marriage age" for lack of better term.

I was looking for a descriptive, nonjudgmental and nonpejorative term. The term I was trying to translate was originally in Hebrew - *רווקות מאוחרת*, which according to Google Translate, translates to *Late bachelorhood* but I wasn't sure it is correct.
I understand that this is a highly cultural dependent question that carries some weight and was looking for various options from multiple English-speaking cultures.

The article I was reading, by the way, was about people in modern societies choosing to stay single even after the "culturally accepted" marriage age and the various reasons behind it.

Comment: You will need to be careful about the tone. Do you want a term that is neutral? Or that implies the person is somehow a failure because they never married? Or even that they are somehow superior because they are unmarried?

Comment: @BobaFit completely neutral, non judgemental in any way...

Comment: Out of curiosity – what was the original word you were trying to translate?

Comment: @MCEmperor the article was in Hebrew, and the word was "רווקות מאוחרת" which in Google Translate is translated to "Late bachelorhood"

Comment: @Michael What are the nuances of that Hebrew term that you want in the English term? Is it slightly pejorative? Is it part of the term that they are interested (or not at all interested) in making a relationship?  Does the age have to be -in- the phrasing, or simply implied eg "woman of a certain age"? etc etc. What is the context in the original? Is the phrasing in Hebrew a new term there for a new sociological phenomenon? Is the phrase simply descriptive? So many nuances..please add to your question.

Comment: This question seems to me off-topic, in that it has no explanation of the context in which such a term would be needed.  There is, sadly, nothing unusual about the phenomenon of lone old women, for the simple reason that women on average  live longer than men. You need to explain why this characteristic is of interest.  Such a classification could be regarded as offensive.  Describing women as 'spinsters' (or men, for that matter, as bachelors) is widely and rightly frowned on. I see that you have accepted the word 'spinster'.

Comment: @Michael Please see [our help for single-word-request questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and [our help for translation questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info). Currently this question does not match the criteria for either tag.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140568/discussion-on-question-by-michael-how-do-you-name-the-phenomenon-of-being-single).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, added clarification to the question. Hope it helps

Comment: Do you want an ungendered term, or one specific to women?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean those who have *never married,* you can hyphenate it. The Social Security Administration (SSA) uses *never-married* as an adjective (*never-married retirees*) and *the never-married* as a noun, an adjectival noun (like *the poor* or *the elderly*).

> This article focuses on a growing yet understudied subgroup of the
> elderly in the United States—the never-married. The first section,
> based on data from the Current Population Survey and a review of the
> academic literature, examines the current circumstances of
> never-married retirees, particularly their economic and health
> well-being.
>
> [[ssa.gov]](https://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/ssb/v67n2/v67n2p25.html)

Answer (score 33):

The traditional term for a woman who has never been married is "spinster". While it technically applies to women of any age, it is more associated with older single women. It's not frequently used these days because it carries some bad associations, but it does accurately describe the situation you are talking about.

Comment: Adjectives from AHD - spinsterish, spinsterly

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for more "academic" appropriate word. But I understand there's no such word

Comment: The source of the word is... Strange. It refers to the frequent occupation of single adult women of spinning wool into yarn. Thus spin-ster.

Comment: For a while, I was determined to be a spinster in both senses of the word, but I discovered that spinning is just not my thing.

Comment: The -ster suffix indicates a female

Comment: Etymonline fleshes out the source of the word: https://www.etymonline.com/word/spinster

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg Magister, that one is a big masculine singular from Latin.  Buster, it's time for the hipsters to muster up some monster that won't fester, one faster than than a postmaster generalization that "-ster suffix indicates female."   Mister.

Answer (score 22):

*Old maid* :

[AHD *old maid*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=old%20maid)

noun 1. (Offensive) Used as a disparaging term for a woman who is no longer young and has not married.

adjective old-maidish

(The word *maid* without *old* can refer to an unmarried girl or woman, per AHD.)

Comment: The use of "maid" or "maiden" to mean "unmarried woman" are both archaic, it should be pointed out

Comment: @NickMatteo The one remaining context where "maiden" to mean "unmarried woman" is still common is in the phrase "maiden name".

Answer (score 13):

To be neutral and objective, you could simply use *unmarried* (if you consider only (formal) marriage) or *single* (if you want to possibly include non-married partners), and leave the age aspect to the context, implicit, or omitted.

Comment: I'd double-vote this one if I could. It really is the correct neutral term, having absolutely no implications of gender or reasons for that status. If you want to narrow it to those who never married, say just that. There is no reason to try to avoid these.

Comment: This assumes that *married* is the default, but it's in this century, so that's good. (BTW, *simple* and *possible* s/b adverbs: *simply* and *possibly.*)

Comment: @HippoSawrUs Well, yes. _Single_ has both "not married" and "without (sexual) partner" meanings, so perhaps it's best. There's something to which concept is the base and which one carries the negation (un-, non-, etc.), in English and other languages. Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: The OP has clarified that they mean not just unmarried / single, but *never* married.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Indeed. In fact, the context is exactly about being unmarried (or unpartnered?) into late age, so no way around using those or similar words. :-) _Single_ is neutral, but finding neutral words for "old" is hard (though the fault lies more with culture than with the words per se).

Answer (score 1):

For men, there is "confirmed bachelor", which is not pejorative. Just means that the guy has never been married, and does not seem to be on any trajectory to ever get married.

(There is also the idiosyncratic "Norwegian bachelor farmer" concept which played a recurring role in Garrison Keillor's "Prairie Home Companion". The phrase referred, as might be obvious, to a certain kind of single man living out in the country... perhaps having few interactions with any people at all, much less any potential spouse... of any sort.)

It may be worth noting that many of the historical instances of people living their lives without marrying anyone were cases of gay or lesbian people who had to hide their actual personal relationships due to (justified) fear of punishment. In particular, except for historical purposes, it might be misguided to really think in terms of "never married", when all it was was "not being allowed to marry the person you love".

Comment: Prior to the invention of the concept of "sexual orientation" in the 20th century, there were no gay or lesbian people, because the concept didn't exist yet; there were just people who had sex with other people of the same gender.

Comment: @nick012000, but/and some of them did have committed relationships to another individual... but could not be "married".